# Binding one ObservableCollection to two ItemsControl's ItemsSource property, only last ItemsControl updating

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, itemscontrol

Im trying to bind an ObservableCollection to two ItemsControl controls, but only the last ItemsControl is actually updating.

XAML:

```
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="0 10 0 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Tag="LeftSideItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Tag="RightSideItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Code behind where items get added to the ObservableCollection:

```
public partial class DiagramContainer : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Items { get; set; }

    public DiagramContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Items = new ObservableCollection<UIElement>();
        Items.Add(new Button() { Content = "TEST" });
        Items.Add(new TextBox() { Text = "TEST" });
    }
}
```

When i run my application, i get the following result:

[image: unexpected result]

The ItemsControl on the right(second column) is the one that updates, the first one doesnt.

Comment: A `UIElement` can have only a single parent; therefore, it cannot be contained in multiple controls. If `Items` were an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead, both ItemsControls would be updated by the Binding.

Comment: @FrankM Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: There shouldn't be UIElements at all in the source collection of an ItemsSource. You should instead declare an appropriate ItemTemplate, with controls that bind to properties of a data item class. If there are different types of items, declare DataTemplates with appropriate DataType values, or set the ItemsControl's ItemTemplateSelector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add same `UIElement` to two different logical parent. Which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.